# monacaのアプリ内でアラームを使いたい

Tags: monaca

monacaでアプリ開発をしております。
フォーラムでmonacaではバックグラウンドでの実行はサポートしていないとありますが
作成中のアプリで指定した時刻にアラームが鳴るような機能を取り入れたいと考えております。
参考資料や、やり方をご存知の方は是非ご教示して頂けませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プラグインを使用しない方法ですと、
例えばバックエンドでPUSH通知を行う方法です。
アプリからサーバへ通知登録し、サーバからAPIを使用してPUSH通知を行います。
ただし送信数が限られているので現実的ではないでしょう。

後はCordovaプラグインを使用する方法しか思いつきません。
例えば[このプラグイン](https://github.com/uniclau/AlarmPlugin)を使用するなどしてOSのアラームを設定する方法です。
ですが、MonacaでCordovaプラグインを使用しようと思うとゴールド以上のプランでないと開発できません。